# Symfony2 saves Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection in database not the name

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Hi I am facing an that i cant not find the solution of it, so for a help.

I have two entities: Cast and Artists. In cast from i have actor, actress which will be field by Artist table, I used this code:

for that :

```
namespace Bbd\MyAppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class CastType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('actor', 'entity', array(
            'class'    => 'BbdMyAppBundle:Artist',
            'property' => 'name',
            'multiple' => true,
            'label'    => 'Artist',
            'required' => false,

        ))
        ->add('actress')
        ->add('content')
    ;
}
```

there can be multiple actor or actress. so in db it saves like:

```
Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection@000000006f69bd7b000000001772666a
```

in the actor field. i dont why, it should save the id or name.

here is the cast orm:

```
Bbd\MyAppBundle\Entity\Cast:
type: entity
repositoryClass: Bbd\MyAppBundle\Repository\CastRepository
table: cast
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        generator: { strategy: AUTO }
fields:
    actor:
        type: text
        nullable: true
    actress:
         type: text
         nullable: true
oneToOne:
    content:
        targetEntity: Content
        inversedBy: cast
        joinColumn:
             name: content_id
             referencedColumnName: id
             onDelete: CASCADE
```

Artist ORM

```
Bbd\MyAppBundle\Entity\Artist:
type: entity
repositoryClass: Bbd\MyAppBundle\Repository\ArtistRepository
table: artist
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        generator: { strategy: AUTO }
fields:
    name:
        type: string
        length: 255
        unique: true
    bangla_name:
        type: string
        length: 255
        unique: true
    priority:
        type: integer
    birth:
        type: date
    sex:
        type: string
        length: 6
    bio_english:
        type: text
    bio_bangla:
        type: text
```

Thanks for help..

Comment: You are storing artists in cast entity using text type its really not a good idea its better to have an association between cast and artist like `OneToMany`,`ManyToMany` which best suits for your structure before building i suggest you to read official docs [`Databases and Doctrine`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html) which also has examples with good explanation

Comment: I have total 20 cast fields, so if i set relation then there will so many tables right? thanks for your suggestion..

Comment: No there will be one relation between your cast and artist entity and a junction table which will have relate cast and artists just have a look at [`Doctrine's many to many`](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional)

Comment: thanks.. i read that before, but the problem i am facing is cant design my orm.. like i have actor, actress  here if i set many to many and junction table will have cast_id and artists_id then where will i get that castid? can you give me a sample orm from my above example?

Answer (score 0):

According to your scenario i can suggest you have a `ManyToMany` association between your `Cast` and `Artist` entity each cast have many artists and each artist can appear in morethan one cast

Your `Artist` entity will look like

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/** @Entity **/
class Artist
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Cast", inversedBy="artists")
     * @JORM\oinTable(name="cast_artists")
     **/
    private $cast;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->cast = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

And `Cast` entity will have a mapping like

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/** @Entity **/
class Cast
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Artist", mappedBy="cast")
     **/
    private $artists;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->artists = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
    public function addArtist($artists) {
        $this->artists[] = $artists;
        return $this;
    }
    public function removeArtist($artists) {
        $this->artists->removeElement($artists);
    }
    public function getArtists() {
        return $this->artists;
    }
}
```

Once you have added all artists record you can create a cast record by selecting multiple artists whether its actor/actress